# Compiling 32bits qt sources on a 64bit Debian environement

Tags: c++, qt, debian, cross-compiling, xlib

I want to build 32 bits applications on my Debian 64 bits environment.

So, I'm trying to compile the Qt sources in order to get the 32 bits libraries.

I am trying to use the following configure command:

```
./configure -platform linux-g++-32
```

Unfortunately, I get an error as below:

```
Basic XLib functionality test failed!
 You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing
```

But when I do the following:

```
./configure -platform linux-g++-64
```

It's working fine.

Any guesses?

Comment: You'll need the packages for 32bit gcc and the 32bit versions of various libraries. Watch out for packages like "x11-32bit-dev", etc. (don't have exact package names at hand, being on opensuse here). my approach is usually to install them one after another as configure complains. Also check the feature summary of configure if everything you need is enabled (freetype, all X features, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the the official documentation and dependencies mentioned in there, try this:

> `sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386 libfontconfig1-dev:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libxcursor-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxfixes-dev:i386 libxft-dev:i386 libxi-dev:i386 libxrandr-dev:i386 libxrender-dev:i386`