# Compiling 32bit Qt on 64bit Linux - fatal error: gnu/lib-names-32.h

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Edit: I finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359098/compiling-32bits-qt-sources-on-a-64bit-debian-environement).  I'd been doing searches that were too specific and when I did a more general search I found that.

I'm trying to compile a 32bit version of Qt 5.6.2 on 64bit Linux Mint, but I'm getting the error `fatal error: gnu/lib-names-32.h`.

Just to go through what I've done, I used the below configuration command:

```
./configure -platform linux-g++-64 -xplatform linux-g++-32 -prefix /home/matthew/Qt/Qt5.6.2-S32 -static -opensource -confirm-license -make libs
```

I then built it with `make -j4`.  I got some compilation errors which where solved by installing `gcc-multilib` and `g++-multilib`, but then ran into another error.

Searching for solutions to the latest error, most people suggest installing `libx32gcc-4.8-dev` and `libc6-dev-i386`, but I still get the same error.

Does anybody know what I need to install to build 32bt Qt on 64bit Linux Mint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359098/compiling-32bits-qt-sources-on-a-64bit-debian-environement). I'd been doing searches that were too specific and when I did a more general search I found the answer.

Comment: Could you add some content from your link to your answer? That way it is preserved in the event your link doesn't work in the future. :)

Comment: The link describes to install  `sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386 libfontconfig1-dev:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libxcursor-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxfixes-dev:i386 libxft-dev:i386 libxi-dev:i386 libxrandr-dev:i386 libxrender-dev:i386`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing ia32 libs.

`sudo aptitude install ia32-libs`

Are you following a tutorial? If so, please, include the link. Could you also please explain your motivation to install 32b Qt libs on your 64b machine?

Comment: I just found the solution in another stackoverflow question.  I've edited my question to include a link to the answer.  As for why I want to build 32bit Qt on a 64bit machine, it's so I can do 32bit builds of my application for people who are running 32bit Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on the `Linux Mint 18.3 x64`, but all solutions found here did't solve the problem.

I've made some dig up and found that the only headers i have is these:

```
>find /usr/include -iname lib-names*
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names-64.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names.h
```

Seems this package (`libc6-dev:amd64`) is responsible for these files:

```
>dpkg -S /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names-64.h
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names-64.h
>dpkg -S /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names.h
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names.h
```

I've tried to remove it:

```
>sudo apt remove libc6-dev:amd64
... to DELETE:
  build-essential g++ g++-5 g++-5-multilib g++-multilib gcc-5-multilib gcc-multilib lib32stdc++-5-dev libc6-dev
  libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libstdc++-5-dev libx32stdc++-5-dev
```

If try to reinstall the deleted packages nothing would change. But if change one package just like that (`libc6-dev:i386` instead of `libc6-dev`):

```
>sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ g++-5 g++-5-multilib g++-multilib gcc-5-multilib gcc-multilib lib32stdc++-5-dev libc6-dev:i386
libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libstdc++-5-dev libx32stdc++-5-dev
```

Now it has installed the required headers:

```
>find /usr/include -iname lib-names*
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names-32.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names-64.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/lib-names.h
```

It looks like some dependency links are broken or not complete.